# Verifying post value with database

Tags: php, pdo

I know some of you might not agree with this but Its good to do. Below you will find my two tables.

Table `Item`

```
pid     Name
1        cat
2        dogs
3        cows
```

Table `Category`

```
CatID    pid  Name
11        1   banana
33        1   apple
44        2   strawberry
```

Basically I have a Select option and the option might looks like the one below

```
<option selected="" value="33">apple</option>
```

now if I was to change the `value` to a `letter` or `number` or leave it `blank` `value=""`

Then I click on my submit button.

In the page which I am posting to I have

```
if(isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['length']) && isset($_POST['Qty']) && isset($_POST['Category'])){ 
        $pid = $_POST['pid'];
        $length = $_POST['length'];
        $qty = $_POST['Qty'];
        $Category = $_POST['Category'];
        $wasFound = false;

<-I have a query here ->

 <-I have another if statement here which should run if everything is okay ->
}
```

**<-I have a query here ->** *this is where my problem is*

I have an individual query which should change with the database to verify that what the user is posting is in the database. This is general to make sure that the user have not done something that they should not have.

```
     dbconnect();
     $statement = $db->prepare("
     SELECT * FROM Category WHERE CatID =:Cat
     LIMIT 1
     ");
     $statement->bindParam('Cat',$Category);
     $statement->execute();
     $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
     exit();
     }
```

I have run query both when I have change the value and it doesn't prove the item getting add to the cart `BUT` even when I haven't change anything, it still doesn't work. `I do not get an error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, have your `dbconnect()` as described in [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info).

Second, make your code more consistent

```
 dbconnect();
 $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Category WHERE CatID = ?");
 $statement->execute(array($Category));
 if (!$statement->fetch()) {
     exit();
 }
```

for your form you can use a bit more intelligent approach (for which, I believe, named placeholders were invented):

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM Category WHERE CatID = :Category AND pid = :pid
                                   AND length = :length AND qty = :qty";
 $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
 unset($_POST['submit']); // get rid of all extra fields in POST
 $statement->execute($_POST); // and then pass it in execute()
 if (!$statement->fetch()) {
     exit();
 }
```

in order to find some inconsistency in your code, add some debug output

Comment: thanks for your help. I have one question to ask you. Will you recommend me doing this individual for the other post contents or just do it one statement?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your question. if you need to get many posts, do it in one statement, getting all the posts with fetchAll()

Comment: @YouCommonSense i was use `category` as an example in this post because I also need to verifying for `pid` and `length`

Comment: if all of them must belong to single row - yes, you have to check using single query

Comment: I am not sure if you have your tables joined properly.

Comment: looking at your edit, I am wondering a few things. why didnt u add `$Category $pid and $length` how will `:` know which variable to refer to?

Comment: also `$qty` is not in the database it is an input field for `quantity`. Your updated answer will never work so please delete it so that no one get confuse please

Comment: alright. Anyways I tested it and it didnt work. I didnt include `Qty` because that is not in my database

Comment: I know why because I am passing it to a Jquery then from that. The Jquery then send it to the cart page. Maybe that's why

Comment: Well, it was just a suggestion. you may use it or you may not. Answers here aren't supposed to be a flawlessly working code for your application but rather examples to follow

Answer (score 0):

I think on the line

```
 if ($statement->rowCount() > 0)
```

You meant < 0.   Exiting if rowCount > 0 means exiting if the category WAS found in the database.  I think you meant to exit if it was not found.

You should probably at least inform the user they chose and invalid category also.

Comment: I did what u said and I doesnt work... The item still get added even when I change the value to letter and even when i leave it blank

Comment: so you downvote my answer because I'm not magically able to read parts of your code that you didn't share? outrageous.